# Why must this be a closed curve?

Tags: functions

Let $V(x,y)$ represent a two-variable positive definite function, i.e., $V(x,y):\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies

1. If $x\ne 0$ or $y\ne 0$, then $V(x,y)\ge 0$
2. $V(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y=0$

For any given real number $C$, $V(x,y)=C$ represents a curve(excluded the condition empty set).  Why must this curve be a closed curve?  I can't prove it.

Comment: Is $V$ assumed to be differentiable? Also what definition of curve are you using?

Comment: The OP originally mentioned that this problem is related to differential equations.  @DavidChan, is $V$ smooth and continuous?  Also, isn't it possible for $V(x,y)=C$ to represent more than one closed curve?  Please state all the assumptions you used.

Comment: @dani_s Joel Reyes Noche V is smooth and continuous. And my question is "V(x,y)=C can just represent a simple closed curve? If this is right, why?"

Answer (score 0):

If there is no continuity
restriction on $V$, 
then it is obviously false.

For example,
if $z>\max(|V(x, y)|)$ for $ |x| \le 2, |y| \le 2$,
redefine
$V_1(1, y) = z+1$
for $-1 \le y \le 1$.

Then the set with
$V_1(x, y) = z+1$
has a line segment as part of it,
so it is not closed.